# Most efficient way to calculate running totals in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

If you are keeping track of running totals such as the following:

```
A     B      C         D         E
-----------------------------------------
Type  Value  Total_AA  Total_BB  Total_CC
AA    1      1         0         0
AA    2      3         0         0
BB    30     3         30        0
BB    40     3         70        0
CC    100    3         70        100
CC    200    3         70        300
```

Which formula is more efficient for Excel to calculate (for example) Total_AA?

```
=IF(A101="AA", C100+B101, C100)
```

or

```
=SUMIF(A:A, "AA", B:B)
```

The first requires 1 conditional test and 1 sum, but row N can't be calculated until row (N-1) is calculated, which in turn can't be calculated until row (N-2) is calculated, etc.

The second requires O(N) conditional tests and O(N) sums.

Normally I'd assume the first method is more efficient, but I don't know if Excel has some internal processes or optimizations that would invalidate that assumption. For example, maybe the dependency of row N's formula result on row (N-1)'s formula result is a costly operation in Excel?

For context, my use case will have about 20,000 rows of Values and about 20 different Types.

Answer (score -1):

*You need SUMIF formula with little modifications:*

[image]

- Formula in cell `C7`, fill it across:

  ```
  =IF($A7<>RIGHT(C$6,2),"",SUMIF($A$7:$A7,$A7,$B$7:$B7))
  ```

*Adjust cell references and criteria search (`C6:F6`) in the formula as needed.*

Comment: This does not attempt to answer the question.

Comment: @AlexM,, could you please write your concern that why is wrong,, help me to improve !!

Comment: Question: **"Which formula is more efficient for Excel to calculate (for example) Total_AA?, `IF` or `SUMIF`**?" Your answer: "You can do this with `SUMIF`." You need my help to understand why this is not an attempt to answer the question??

Comment: @AlexM,, unfortunately both of the formula shown by the OP unable to produce expected result,, and not suitable to the issue,, so that I've suggested an improved `SUMIF`,, is working as well as producing expected results !!

Comment: "expected results" is a discussion of the efficiency of two different approaches.

Comment: @AlexM,, efficiency should be counted if and when the formula works,, both of the show formula by OP doesn't works, also OP both formula are Hard core,, targets AA only. *And my approach is an extension of the `SUMIF` what OP has tried !!*